# how to estimate paid_storage_size_diff?

Tags: contract, fee

Example:

I deploy a contract(gen a multi sign address,3owners) or tranfer 0 amount to a KT1 address (for multisign address send money to a tz1 address)

I can estimate fee by: https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/PROTO_003_FEES.md

But only know fee is not enough. I need to know `paid_storage_size_diff` like following, at last:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way to estimate it is to use the CLI like you've done. Otherwise, you need to know the contract's high water mark (the most storage it ever held), the current size of its storage, whether the operation will increase the storage beyond the high water mark and if so by how much.

However, I note that in your screenshot you are transferring from a tz1 to a KT1.

Comment: 1  can't use CLI. only RPC.    ----------

2.1 deploy a contract  will pay storage for KT1 address. need  paid_storage_size_diff   --------


2.2 a KT1 address(3 owners),if I need transfer XTZ from this KT1 address to tz1 address, I need do: transfer owner's address 0 amount and parament to tz1 address. this will change KT1 address's storage. also need  paid_storage_size_diff

Comment: thanks very much。 if I set storage_limit =100. and minimal_nanotez_per_byte = 1000 nꜩ/B and make sure operation will not let storage is big than storage_limit. it will call 100* 1000 at most. thanks I got it